# How have 4 percentage slice after groupby?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
city     age
paris    8
paris    12
paris    45
paris    65
LA       65
LA       78
LA       42
```

I would like to groupby city and know age percentage in 4 interval :

- % of people where age <16 years (slice1)
- 16 < % of people where age < 30 (slice2)
- 30 < % of people where age < 40 (slice3)
- 40 < % of people where age   (slice4)

Expected output like this:

```
   city     slice1 slice2 slice3 slice4
   paris    2%     6%     70%    22%
   LA       1%     40%    9%     50%
```

How can I do this with Pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to define age groups and [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `normalize='index'` to compute the proportion per city:

```
age_groups = [0,16,30,40]
age_labels = [f'slice{i+1}' for i in range(len(age_groups))]

ages = pd.cut(df['age'], bins=age_groups+[float('inf')],
              labels=age_labels, right=False)

df_out = (pd.crosstab(df['city'], ages, normalize='index')
            .reindex(age_labels, axis=1, fill_value=0)
         )
```

output:

```
>>> df_out
age    slice1  slice2  slice3  slice4
city                                 
LA        0.0       0       0     1.0
paris     0.5       0       0     0.5
```

as percent:

```
>>> df_out*100
age    slice1  slice2  slice3  slice4
city                                 
LA        0.0       0       0   100.0
paris    50.0       0       0    50.0
```